# I have followed the steps in 'Getting Started with Facebook Login for Web' but adding the Facebook SDK for Javascript does not seem to work

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I tried following the steps outlined in '[Getting Started with Facebook Login for Web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/)' however they do not seem to be working.

I have followed the steps on this page; I retrieved my App ID (Step 1), I added the Facebook SDK for Javascript (Step 2) (Minus the channel URL, which I read elsewhere in the documentation is optional, as I am working on this page offline rather than hosted on a server), I then added the login code (Step 3).

I'm not sure why it isn't working. I am getting the error 'Failed to load resource' in the console log.

Full Code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '1233456789', // App ID
    //channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any auth related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct user interaction (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
</script>
<!--Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to-->
<!--present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked.-->
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (I haven't pasted any code as I have literally copy-pasted code from the tutorial page, the only difference I made was adding in my App Id and removing the channel URL)

Comment: What resource? Note that Facebook snippet will need to download a javascript file from the Internet anyways...

Comment: file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely, the Facebook SDK download line starts with `//`, not `http://` or `https://`. That means that the script will be downloaded with using the same protocol of the embedding page. You are opening a local file, which shows up as `file://` in the navigation bar, so the browser tries to download the SDK via `file://` and fails.

Long story made short: add a `https:` before the two `//`, like this:

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
```

Longer solution (but cleaner): use a local development server. If you have PHP 5.4 installed on your PC, open a command line, navigate to the project folder and then launch:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

The open your browser and enter `localhost:8080` in the address bar.

Comment: Yeah, the file is hosted on my PC (as opposed to a server), but I am connected to the internet. If that is what you mean? 

The file it fails to connect to in the .html application file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js can be reached just fine if I type it in to my browser :/

Comment: Wait a second, the file is `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` or `file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`??

Comment: It shows up as `file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` in the console log. 

I have posted the code but it is *exactly* the same as the code in Step 3 of the guide (with my App Id, minus the channelURL)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29561/discussion-between-stefano-sanfilippo-and-shimmergeek)